# how to reduce react createPortal import cost

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, react-portal

import cost for createPortal from react-dom is 131kb (gzipped: 42kb)

i tried to import it as look like as createRoot that can import from "react-dom/client" but i can't do that.
is there any way to reduce this cost?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you use nextJS and care about the "First Load JS" size, it won't change with this import or without. So, you can use it as it is and sleep well. The bundle size is also the same.

Answer (score -1):

No. it is exported from `react-dom` so you can't import it from `react-dom/client`. and the cost is not a big deal. why do you care about it at all?

Comment: for increase performance

Comment: you can't do anything about it, and as I said it's not a big deal. care about the performance when writing your components and logic.